# Listing global variable

Tags: variables

Is there any way to list all global variable?
I'm guessing i could maintain a list where multiple value represent a global variable but that feel a bit weird. is there an official way to do that? (looked into the docs but didn't find anything)

I'm only talking about `g:variable_name` here.

Comment: hmm, didn't found that when I searched -- anyway, looked at the two answer there, and yes they do answer this question too, but given the two answer there aren't repeated there, I wonder: should I accept this as duplicate or not? (especially since it's mostly about global variable, but I guess you can apply it to other variable type) @statox

Comment: If you are not sure you can let the community decide: Your question should now appear in the [close votes queue](https://vi.stackexchange.com/review/close) if enough people think it's a duplicate it will be closed as so and otherwise it will stay open. It's not super important anyway now that both questions are linked it might be useful for future readers.

Comment: you're right :) Thanks for the clarification @statox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command will list all global variables:

```
:let g:
```

Using `:let` by itself will list all variables, and passing it just a prefix (such as `g:` or `b:` or `v:`) will filter the output to only include variables in that prefix. Therefore, `:let g:` will show you all global variables.

Comment: oh my! This look way easier than I thought...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use `:echo keys(g:)` as `g:` is the directory used to store global variables.